# Application cannot load most of the mjs file from @azure/msal-browser @azure/msal-react

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, electron, msal-react

I'm trying to implement MSAL login in my React application (React + .Net Core + Electron.Net). I installed @azure/msal-react and @azure/msal-browswer. When trying to run my application, I got errors related to .mjs file. Most of it is about:

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

[image]

This my package.json file. Do I miss out anything? I tried to install react-scripts, but it doesn't help.

```
{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.7.1",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^2.0.10",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^4.3.3",
    "antd": "^3.26.13",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "frameless-titlebar": "^2.1.4",
    "i18next": "^19.3.4",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.4",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "opentype.js": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dnd": "^9.5.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.16.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.3.1",
    "react-microsoft-login": "^1.15.0",
    "react-onedrive-filepicker": "^0.1.3",
    "react-outside-click-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-rectangle-selection": "^1.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-zendesk": "^0.1.9",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "velocity-animate": "^1.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "mjs",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "import",
        [
          {
            "libraryName": "antd",
            "style": "css"
          }
        ]
      ],
      [
        "syntax-dynamic-import"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.0.8",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "element-react": "^1.4.7",
    "element-theme-default": "^1.4.13",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "less": "^3.0.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react-click-outside": "^3.0.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.5",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Here is my test environment, it is working for the Sign In Microsoft. it will pop up the screen when I click on the Sign In with Pop up button.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w1bbuc-astsm1?file=package.json

But as my development environment has more components, somehow it is not working. Cannot pop up any screen when click on the button.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @DasariKamali, here is my test environment which is working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w1bbuc-astsm1?file=package.json